# Get Event for changing width of canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, events, canvas

When I change my canvas width on runtime, can I get an Event  when the width of my canvas change ?

Changing my width on runtime trough:

```
myCanvas.width = myCanvas.width + 1;
```

Is there an event like:

```
private void CanvasWidthChanged(object sender, WidthChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: You don't have to add tags to the title. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Comment: What do you want this for? sounds like a really poor way to do layout.

Answer (score 4):

Use the SizeChanged Event.

```
myCanvas.SizeChanged += myCanvas_SizeChanged;

private void myCanvas_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx) event.

There's a [WidthChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.sizechangedeventargs.widthchanged.aspx) property in the event args that you can use to see if the width changed.

Comment: Mhh Strange if I do it in XAML there is no reaction but if I do it in the behind code like myCanvas.SizeChanged += myCanvas_SizeChanged; there is an event

Comment: Are you sure? If you add the xaml code (don't mind the intellisense) does it work anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can create own class inherited from Canvas and proces changed of size in this class. Something like

```
public class DXFCanvas : Canvas
{
    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);

        // Your action ...
        // (SizeChangedInfo contains old and new size)
    }
}
```